# Simple socket call returning socket.gaierror: [Errno 8]

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, error-handling

I have this really simple code:

```
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
```

That should be returning my IP adress.

But it is returning an error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Any idea?

Some details:

```
socket.gethostname()
```

returns:

```
'airdevincent2'
```

Comment: how you unfolded those to pinpoint what is causing the error?

Comment: what happens if you do a 'ping $(hostname --fqdn)' at the command line? (assuming this is linux.)

Comment: I am on MacOS, this command is not working

Answer (score 2):

Answer found!!!

I am on MacOs and the /etc/hosts file didn't contains any mention to the "airdevincent2" host.

So I added this line:

```
127.0.0.1   airdevincent2
```

Et voilà!

Comment: "I am on MacOs and the /etc/hosts file didn't contains any mention to ..." was very helpful. Thanks a lot.